# C# Authentication from a WinForm

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I have ready many SO articles on authentication but cannot get my app to function properly.  I am trying to provide authentication credentials to a server to access a resource via the servers REST api.  I am able to do this fine when using the Sharepoint REST api (which uses the SharePointOnlineCredentials and most notably the GetAuthenticationCookie method for the class) but I believe my issue in this application is the lack of a properly configured Authentication cookie.  My code for reference...

```
public static async Task<string> GetWebPageProjectData(string url)
    {
        string username = "SampleUser@Domain.com";
        string password = "SamplePassword#!";

        var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, securePassword, "Domain");

        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;


        /* THE ISSUE IS THE LACK OF AN AUTHENTICATION COOKIE !?!?!    */
        try
        {
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credential })
            {
                var uri = new Uri("http://webpage/location");


                // ***WORKS W/ SP credentials ***handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));
                //handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies()  What I think needs to be done in some way, shape, or form!?!?

                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "basic" + encoded);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=nometadata"));

                    var query = url;
                    response = await client.GetAsync($"{query}").ConfigureAwait(false);

                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }//end try
        catch (HttpRequestException) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (CookieException)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I've tried numerous variations (preAuthenticate, use of proxy..) of this code with the same result.  Ultimately I end up at a login page set up by my company as this is an intranet web application...What am I missing here?

Comment: It is possible you have more than one issue, but if your authorization is the typical Basic auth then you need a space between the scheme and the paramter - `"Basic " + encoded`

Comment: Also, exceptions can be helpful, try looking at them instead of returning null.

Comment: Crowcoder, thank you for the comments.  I added the space as noted but still getting the same result.  As for the exceptions, this is not production code or remotely polished so i'm just using them to try and see what's going on.  Basically when i had handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri)) uncommented i was catching a null cookie header, which i was able to examine in the catch..

You've touched on the fact that there may be more than 1 issue here...Is there i am completely missing here (conceptually)?

Comment: It is difficult to say without knowing what kind of authentication is required. You create network credentials but never use them. Do you know for a fact that Basic auth is what you want? A typical scenario is to make a request that provides the necessary credentials which fills a `CookieContainer`, then you use that same `CookieContainer` instance to make a second request that gets the data. [I have an example demonstrating this with Asp.Net Membership on my blog](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/authenticating-to-asp-net-membership-provider-programmatically/).

Comment: I thought I "use/configure" the credentials by setting them in the HttpClientHandler and then using this as a parameter to the HttpClient constructor?  I don't know for a fact that Basic auth is what I want.  I'm an embedded dev trying to learn a bit about RESTful apps; this is new to me.  All i know is i'm blocked by a company login page (office365??) I guess I am struggling to obtain the authentication cookie/ticket prior to making the second request which actually obtains the requested resource.  Gunna comb through your blog and see where that gets me.

Comment: If you open the browser developer tools and make sure the Network trace is on, you can log in through a browser and see what is happening. You would have to reproduce those requests in c#. Make sure you know what is going before you go to far with my blog example, it could be very different than what you need.